# Simple Maths Riddle 6

Tags: riddle, mathematics

A sixth riddle!

> There's a function just
>
> (reserved)
>
> for me
>
> though you need three
>
> of me to complete it.
>
> Don't simplify
>
> (me)
>
> when the top's much larger;
>
> I'll explode
>
> before you know it.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it may be (only may be , not sure!!!)

> Combinatorics (combinations)

There's a function just (reserved) for me

though you need three of me to complete it.

> Expression : $^nC_r $ - three symbols required to complete the expression, also $^nC_r = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ - three 'factorial' terms

Don' t simplify when the top's much larger

> Evaluating $^nC_r$ becomes tedious, if $n$ is large, (provided $r$ is not very large or small ) .
>  $$$$
>  For e.g, $^{520}C_{14} = 1016179801403563036214357760$

I'll explode before you know it

> May be the same as above or **combinatorial explosion** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion

Comment: Thank you! Is it really correct?

Comment: Yep! Note that the function was originally a reference to the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) with parameters given by $\sf{Hy(x\mid N,d,n)}$ and density function $$p(x)=\frac{\binom dx \binom{N-d}{n-x}}{\binom Nn}$$ and as you can see, it is made up of three combinations. Great job!

Answer (score 1):

**First Attempt (possibility to be correct: 20%)**

> cone?

```
There's a function just

(reserved)

for me
```

> Volume of a cone : $pi*r^2*h/3$

```
though you need three

of me to complete it.
```

> denominator = $3$, complete: without it?

```
Don't simplify

(me)

when the top's much larger;

I'll explode
```

> pi is just sooooo long... when simplified...

```
before you know it.
```